# Record in a separate Workbook/Worksheet the username of the person closing a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to create a Macro which will record the username and date-time for users opening and closing a variable workbook, ie the workbook being opened and closed will change.

So far I have code that will record the above info for when the work book is opened:-

```
Option Explicit

Private iNextRow As Long
Const HIDDEN_SHEET As String = "Sheet3"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Worksheets(HIDDEN_SHEET)
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = 1
.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Value = Environ("UserName")

Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "01/01/2000 00:01"
.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Value = Format(Date + Time, "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss")
End With
 iNextRow = 1

End Sub
```

Can anyone help with the code to record the workbook being closed?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the Workbook_BeforeClose event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario I prefer to keep the data out of a worksheet as there is always a risk somebody overwrites it. Instead, try using a `defined name`.

Here is an example that captures user name and timestamp information on open and close:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StoreUserInfo "Open", Environ("UserName"), VBA.Now()
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    StoreUserInfo "Close", Environ("UserName"), VBA.Now()
End Sub

Function StoreUserInfo(eventType As String, userName As String, timeStamp As String)
    If (eventType = "Open") Then
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="OpenUser", RefersTo:=userName, Visible:=False
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="OpenTime", RefersTo:=timeStamp, Visible:=False
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CloseUser", RefersTo:=userName, Visible:=False
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CloseTime", RefersTo:=timeStamp, Visible:=False
    End If
End Function
```

Note two things:

1. The `.Add` function overwrites any existing data so you don't end up with multiple names
2. The `Visible:=False` means that a user cannot see the information on the worksheet by typing in the defined name (e.g. `OpenUser`) in the top-left hand box

You can retrieve the information quite easily:

```
Sub RetriveInformation()
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Names("OpenUser").RefersTo   //prints username e.g. =JohnDoe
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Names("OpenTime").RefersTo   //prints timestamp e.g. ="15/07/2014 15:10:48"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the close event, just use the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event, as there's no `Workbook_Close` if you're wondering.

Also, you seem to be hard coding the number of rows to 65536. Workbooks can potentially have many more for Excel 2007 and later versions, although you're fine for Excel 2003 or previous.

Since you seem to be using column A for usernames and column B for dates, if I were you I'd have a single cell, e.g. C1, to record the *next* available row number for entries, starting with 1. So, before you add an entry into the "hidden" sheet, check the number in cell C1 and use it as your row index for the username and date entries. Then update it to whatever C1 was +1. This way, you always have the next index available. If anything goes wrong, before you add an entry you can check to make sure the row doesn't have any existing data or you might overwrite it.

Comment: thanks i'll look into Workbook_BeforeClose().

The hardcode is lazy coding and knowing that it wont be needed, the sheet i'll be using will be overwritten daily and people wont cover more than 50 rows. Thanks again!

Comment: @LuckySevens: No problem. Just remember that if the requirements for this sheet subsequently change and it doesn't get overwritten, etc. then you may get into trouble. But if you're sure it will always work this way, then it's fine I guess.